# JQuery Sort of an array with 3 elements

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have an array which contains 3 elements:

> Field1
>   Field2
>   Field3

I need to sort this array by Field2. I have been trolling through the internet and all I seem to see is arrays with only one element being sort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of objects with jquery or javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503900/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/how-to-sort-an-array-of-javascript-objects and adapt it to your needs

Answer (score 2):

You can supply a comparison function to the `sort` method:

```
 theArray.sort(function(a, b){
   if (a.Field2 == b.Field2) return 0;
   if (a.Field2 < b.Field2) return -1;
   return 1;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I don't understand your problem. To sort an need a condition to specify an order.

When you sort this array by Field2 then I guess Field2 would be the first element. And What would come second? And why? Field3 or Field1?

Comment: I believe that it's an array of object, where each object has the three properties.