# jQuery sortable: How to automatic order <li> in a sortable by <li> classes?

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable

I echo some `<li class='A'>` or class='B' or class='C' in #a sortable div.
Then user moves them in #b sortable div. I need that in #b the `<li>` **automaticly** sort themselves by **desc** alfabetic order of **their class** (C->B->A) and, in second time, by alfabetic order of the `<li>`'s **content** (`<li class='X'>content</li>`).

How have I to script in `<head>`?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI has nice sortable stuff.  Here are the [demos](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/).

Try using the [update event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-update) to enforce your ordering.

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
 update: function(event, ui) {
   $("find the LIs you want").sort(
     function(a, b){
       var aName = a.name.toLowerCase();
       var bName = b.name.toLowerCase(); 
       return ((aName < bName) ? -1 : ((aName > bName) ? 1 : 0));
    });
 }
});
```

The sort code is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503900/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-with-jquery-or-javascript).

Comment: I did it with sortable! I need the "automatic" part!