# Sorting array of objects by a single value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to figure out how to sort my array by objects in that array. In this example I want to be be able to sort my array by player name, or by player score.

```
var topPlayers = new Array();

$(".player").each( function(i) {
    topPlayers[i] = {};
    topPlayers[i]["name"] = $(this).children(".name").text();
    topPlayers[i]["score"] = $(this).children(".score").text();
});


topPlayers.sort(function(a.name,b.name){return a.name-b.name}); //This is the line of code I can't figure...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of javascript objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/how-to-sort-an-array-of-javascript-objects) and [How to sort an array of objects with jquery or javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503900/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-with-jquery-or-javascript).

Comment: Btw, subtracting two strings does not make a lot of sense... what do you expect `'foo' - 'bar'` to be? If you have seen this in other implementations, then that's because both values have been expected to be numbers. In that case it is more concise to use subtraction than comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting by name:

```
topPlayers.sort(function(a, b)
{ 
  if ( a.name > b.name ) return 1;
  else if ( a.name < b.name ) return -1;
  else return 0;
});
```

Sorting by score:

```
topPlayers.sort(function(a, b)
{ 
  return a.score - b.score;
});
```

Comment: If the names are equal, you should return `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The `sort` method takes a function that makes a comparison and returns a number depending on the result:

```
topPlayers.sort(function(a,b){
  if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
  if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
  return 0;
});
```

For numeric values you can just subtract them to get the right return value:

```
topPlayers.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.score - b.score;
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `>`/`<` operators on characters this doesn't work on Safari, IOS devices. Haven't testet on other mobile devices. Instead use: `a.name.charCodeAt(0)-b.name.charCodeAt(0)`

Comment: @NULL: That's not sufficient. Why is no one mentioning `strA.localeCompare(strB)`?

Comment: @FelixKling So if you know that all along why didn't you post it in the first place?

Comment: @NULL: You mean as an answer? Because this question is a duplicate. If you mean as comment to this answer, I did not look that closely at it, because, again, it's a duplicate.

Comment: @NULL: Do you have any reference to string comparison being broken on Safari IOS? I can't find anything about it. Comparing the first character of the string doesn't do the same thing, so that won't suffice.