# JQuery get data from JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

This is part of the JSON i get from foursquare.

**JSON**

```
tips: {
    count: 2,
    groups: [
    {
        type: "others",
        name: "Tips from others",
        count: 2,
        items: [
        {
            id: "4e53cf1e7d8b8e9188e20f00",
            createdAt: 1314115358,
            text: "najjači fitness centar u gradu",
            canonicalUrl: "https://foursquare.com/item/4e53cf1e7d8b8e9188e20f00",
            likes: {
                count: 2,
                groups: [
                {
                    type: "others",
                    count: 2,
                    items: []
                }],
                summary: "2 likes"
            },
            like: false,
            logView: true,
            todo: {
                count: 0
            },
            user: {
                id: "12855147",
                firstName: "Damir",
                lastName: "P.",
                gender: "male",
                photo: {
                    prefix: "https://irs1.4sqi.net/img/user/",
                    suffix: "/AYJWDN42LMGGD2QE.jpg"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            id: "4e549e39152098912f227203",
            createdAt: 1314168377,
            text: "ajd da vidimo hocu li znati ponoviti",
            canonicalUrl: "https://foursquare.com/item/4e549e39152098912f227203",
            likes: {
                count: 0,
                groups: []
            },
            like: false,
            logView: true,
            todo: {
                count: 0
            },
            user: {
                id: "12855147",
                firstName: "Damir",
                lastName: "P.",
                gender: "male",
                photo: {
                    prefix: "https://irs1.4sqi.net/img/user/",
                    suffix: "/AYJWDN42LMGGD2QE.jpg"
                }
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

I need to get the last tip **text** , the **user** who wrote it and the **date** when he wrote/post it.

*User*: Damir P.

*Date* : 1314115358

*Text*: najjači fitness centar u gradu

I tried with **JQuery** and this works to fetch a non-array value:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    var text= data.response.venue.tips.groups.items.text;
    alert(text);
});
```

But it doesn't work with arrays.

**Result** : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined.

Also I tried with **$.each**, but with no effect.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    $.each(data.response.venue.tips.groups.items.text, function (index, value) {
        console.log(value);
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @JanDvorak He is here to learn. No need to flame him.

Comment: groups is an array as well.

Comment: @Johan I admit, it was badly formulated. All I wanted was to point him to the right resources, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to iterate both the groups and the items. [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) takes a collection as first parameter and `data.response.venue.tips.groups.items.text` *tries* to point to a string. Both `groups` and `items` are arrays.

*Verbose version:*

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {

    // Iterate the groups first.
    $.each(data.response.venue.tips.groups, function (index, value) {

        // Get the items
        var items = this.items; // Here 'this' points to a 'group' in 'groups'

        // Iterate through items.
        $.each(items, function () {
            console.log(this.text); // Here 'this' points to an 'item' in 'items'
        });
    });
});
```

Or more simply:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    $.each(data.response.venue.tips.groups, function (index, value) {
        $.each(this.items, function () {
            console.log(this.text);
        });
    });
});
```

---

In the JSON you specified, the *last* one would be:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    // Get the 'items' from the first group.
    var items = data.response.venue.tips.groups[0].items;

    // Find the last index and the last item.
    var lastIndex = items.length - 1;
    var lastItem = items[lastIndex];

    console.log("User: " + lastItem.user.firstName + " " + lastItem.user.lastName);
    console.log("Date: " + lastItem.createdAt);
    console.log("Text: " + lastItem.text);
});
```

This would give you:

> User: Damir P.
>   Date: 1314168377
>   Text: ajd da vidimo hocu li znati ponoviti

Comment: Excellent. This gets all of the data but how to get the last one ?

Comment: @Vucko What is *the last one*? =)

Comment: In this case, text **najjači fitness centar u gradu** is the last one. So is the last one `item[0].text` or `item[1].text` ? And how to approach this with your code ?

Comment: @Vucko I have updated the answer. But the text you are talking about is the *first* in the array and not the *last*. By *last*, do you mean the last one in the array or the *latest* by the `createdAt` date?

Comment: I meant the last one created.

Comment: @Vucko Ok, then just do a sort on the `createdAt` in the items-array before fetching the item. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503900/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-with-jquery-or-javascript) on how to sort an array. I'm sure you can manage that =)

Answer (score 6):

You're not looping over the items. Try this instead:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    $.each(data.response.venue.tips.groups.items, function (index, value) {
        console.log(this.text);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like:

```
var text= data.response.venue.tips.groups[0].items[1].text;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    $.each(data.response.venue.tips.groups.items, function (index, value) {
        console.log(this.text);
    });
});
```

Comment: hello @satish can we use `console.log(this.text);` out each by creating an array?