# How to call an external json file or a file from a folder

Tags: jquery, json

How to call an external json file or a json file from a folder for this code??? `Jsfiddle` for my code `http://jsfiddle.net/binoymat/cve8gyuy/`

I tried

```
$.getJSON( "{% url 'sampletest.json' %}", function(data){ 

//code inside

});
```

but wasn't able to pull the data.

Comment: was the json url hosted in the same host server u are requesting ?

Comment: Well, rite now, its in my local drive, at a later stage it would be hosted on the server.. so, yes.. Its in the same local server

Comment: are u trying to access the json file from jsfiddle ?

Comment: no.. I have a json file in my project.. i want to call this json file which is within my project and not on any server.. I just want to know how its done on the fiddle i posted

Comment: ok , try this http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/cve8gyuy/1/

Comment: thanks kishore!!! works they way i wanted!!!!

Comment: i think the issue was in the parsing, as getJSON already parses the JSON see my below answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33855454/2074346

Comment: Kishore... How to make the value be displayed inside a div??? i mean in this fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/binoymat/d9f8t9vj/3/   i have added a div.. i want the value from this input to be displayed inside the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getJSON` gets a parsed JSON object. 
See the below sample:

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/cve8gyuy/1/

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/4ls7p", function(data) {
  //code inside
  var items = data;
  var checkIds = [];
  $.each(items, function(k, v) {
    if ($.inArray(v.id, checkIds) == -1) {
      $("#category").append('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.chains + '</option>');
      checkIds.push(v.id);
    }
  });

  $("#category").on('change', function() {
    var dept_number = parseInt($(this).val());
    var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
    var tochange = false;
    var total = 0;
    $.each(items, function(k, v) {
      if (v.id == dept_number) {
        if (tochange == true) {
          $("#category1").append('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.site + '</option>');
          $("#category2").append('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.zone + '</option>');
          $("#category3").append('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.date + '</option>');
        } else {
          $("#category1").html('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.site + '</option>');
          $("#category2").html('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.zone + '</option>');
          $("#category3").html('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.date + '</option>');
          tochange = true;
        }
        total += v.visitors;
      }
    });
    $('#dept-input').val(dept_number);
    $('#price-input').val(total);
  }).change();

  $("select[id^='category']:not(#category)").on('change', function() {
    var dept_number = parseInt($(this).val());
    var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
    $('#dept-input').val(dept_number);
    $('#price-input').val(price);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="category"></select>
<select id="category1"></select>
<select id="category2"></select>
<select id="category3"></select>
<br>
<br>
<label>Dept. num:</label>
<input type="text" id="dept-input"></input>
<br>
<br>
<label>Price:</label>
<input type="text" id="price-input"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate both the groups and the items. [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) takes a collection as first parameter and data.response.venue.tips.groups.items.text tries to point to a string. Both groups and items are arrays.

Verbose version:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {

// Iterate the groups first.
$.each(data.response.venue.tips.groups, function (index, value) {

    // Get the items
    var items = this.items; // Here 'this' points to a 'group' in 'groups'

    // Iterate through items.
    $.each(items, function () {
        console.log(this.text); // Here 'this' points to an 'item' in 'items'
    });
});
});
```

Or more simply:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
$.each(data.response.venue.tips.groups, function (index, value) {
    $.each(this.items, function () {
        console.log(this.text);
    });
});
});
```

In the JSON you specified, the last one would be:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
// Get the 'items' from the first group.
var items = data.response.venue.tips.groups[0].items;

// Find the last index and the last item.
var lastIndex = items.length - 1;
var lastItem = items[lastIndex];

console.log("User: " + lastItem.user.firstName + " " + lastItem.user.lastName);
console.log("Date: " + lastItem.createdAt);
console.log("Text: " + lastItem.text);
});
```

This would give you:

> User: Damir P.
>   Date: 1314168377
>   Text: ajd da vidimo hocu li znati ponoviti

[See the Source answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15219778/2979342)

Comment: something on Plunker pls

Comment: i didn't understand 'data.response.venue.tips.groups' can anyone modify my code and let me know how its done??

Comment: send me your json file here

Comment: It would be of great help if changes are made with my code for eg;- inside the script code... what should i do?? here is the plunker link.. pls edit this http://plnkr.co/edit/r0JAa1Ai6eDNSzrplsOY?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and I added my test json file and you can see that title comes from json's first object 'name' property here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mkdizajn/9d2L1Lrt/1/

Hope that helps you,, I only used more general `ajax` jquery fn.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://mkdizajn.github.io/public/test.json",
    success: function(data){
        $( 'h1' ).text( data[0].name )
    },
});
```

cheers

Comment: almost there... it says "items is not defined" what am I missing?? should i give var = items;???

Comment: can you paste your json in jsfiddle somewhere so I can take a look?