# how to get specific object value inside jquery from json string

Tags: jquery, json, duplicates

This is how I get data inside jQuery:

```
    var jsonList = '[{"region":"NCA","depprt":"Havana, Cuba"},{"region":"NCA","depprt":"Havana, Cuba"}]';

  var jsList = JSON.parse(jsonList);
  var nesels = $.trim(sel);
  var ncaList = jsList.filter(function (obj) { return obj.region == nesels; });
```

In here `ncaList` provide filtered data. Now I want to get only `depprt` from the filtered data to the array without any duplicates. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show us your `sel` string?

Comment: You can use map get on  `ncaList  = ncaList.map(function(o){return o.depprt; })` then you can get unique value using various methods

Comment: @Satpal ys it is working put this as an answer.I will vote.and at the same time how can I remove duplicate values

Comment: in this thread is used the `.each()` method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219435/jquery-get-data-from-json-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map()` to extract only `depprt` like

```
ncaList = ncaList.map(function(o){
     return o.depprt; 
}).filter(onlyUnique);
```

With reference to [@TLindig answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14438954)

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that "**ncalist**" is also in json format as **jslist**.

You can traverse and get required info/fields as :

```html
for(i = 0; i < ncalist.length; i++){
 var depprtVar = ncalist[i]["depprt"];
    // here you can write code to check for duplication in your array and add the depprtVar to array if it is not in the array.

}
```