# Remove caution from json obj

Tags: javascript, string

Here I attached json result.

```
"properties": {
                "id": 99,
                "county": "Ashe",
                "cen_lat": 36.4343964583676,
                "cen_long": -81.5004915302458,
                "county_id": "5",
                "extent": "[-9099469.85881319,4333729.96758589,-9044051.86962052,4381852.80674575]"
            }
```

when I read extent and getting result is

> "[-9099469.85881319,4333729.96758589,-9044051.86962052,4381852.80674575]"

but I need

> [-9099469.85881319,4333729.96758589,-9044051.86962052,4381852.80674575]

How can I get?

Comment: reformat the question.also what is that large number an array of numbers? is it an array of numbers? put your code between two back quotes. It's the same key as the tilde~ next to 1

Comment: [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: try  JSON.parse then repost the question with the results of that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery get data from JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219435/jquery-get-data-from-json-array)

Comment: No mention of jQuery in the question...

Comment: Found it. Convert JSON.parse

Comment: Remove _"caution"_ from?? What is "caution"? Do you meant you want to remove the _quotes_ `"` from it? JSON is all Strings, and I take it you want the actual _Array_ represented by `extent`. In your browser's console, try `JSON.parse("[-9099469.85881319,4333729.96758589,-9044051.86962052,4381852.80674575]");`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments.

`JSON.parse("[-9099469.85881319,4333729.96758589,-9044051.86962052,4381852.80674575]");`