# Sorting out the objects

Tags: javascript, json

My new post: Hi All, This time I made correct changes to  the array of objects with adding "]". Now how do I sort according to value?

> > I am not  sure how to sort out objects, though I have seen it like arrays or objects. It does not seem to work. Please advise

```
var storeData3 = 
  [{ 'key' : 'value1',
   'key' : 'value2' ,
   'key' : 'value3' ,
   'key' : 'value10'}];

storeData3.push({'key':'value6'});
```

Any idea?

Comment: your question is not clear. what exactly do you want to sort and how? please post sample input and desired output.

Comment: You can't use the same key over and over again (to store several values in an object). Objects won't support the push method, you may want to use an array?

Comment: push method related to array object .

Comment: ... also `storeData3` is not an array. Therefore no `push` function available.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503900/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-with-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: @Imperative: Ofcourse he can use the same key again and again, but the previous values will be overwritten with the last one and that is `BAD`

Comment: Sure, but i don't expect that to be desired? ;)

Comment: And only when not in "strict mode"

Comment: Oh sigh... I have to find out more about arrays and  objects and mixture of arrays and objects as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your storeData3 should like this

```
var storeData3 = [
  { 'key' : 'value1' },
  { 'key' : 'value2' },
  { 'key' : 'value3' },
  { 'key' : 'value4' }
]

storeData3.push(  { 'key' : 'value5' });
```

Comment: Thanks but actually i just want to sort according to valueX, ie in the ascending or descending order after the element has been push, say value6 in my old code.

Comment: Hi Thanks  Now found a way with help from [link]( http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort2.shtml)

Comment: Woooo @@" hahaha I can find it, But I am trying to write my own function. But that is good. :D good luck