# How to sort java object on client side by multiple fields?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, sorting

I'm doing my first project using tomcat, jsp, servlets and log4j.

I have a Faculty entity which characterized by the id, name, budget seats and total seats:

```
public class Faculty {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private byte budgetSeats;
    private byte totalSeats;
    ...
}
```

And user should be able to sort `List<Faculty>` passed to jsp page by name, total and budget seats:

```
<select>
  <option value="name">Faculty name</option>
  <option value="budgetSeats">Budget seats</option>
  <option value="totalSeats">Total Seats</option>
</select>
...
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Faculty name</td>
                <td>Faculty budget seats</td>
                <td>Faculty total seats</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
        <c:forEach var="faculty" items="${faculties}">
            <tr>
                <td><a
                    href="<c:url value="controller?command=viewFaculty"> <c:param name="name" value="${faculty.name}"/></c:url>"><c:out
                            value="${faculty.name}"></c:out></a></td>
                <td><c:out value="${faculty.totalSeats}"></c:out></td>
                <td><c:out value="${faculty.budgetSeats}"></c:out></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

I don't want to sort this array using `Comparator` every time user request sorting. How can I sort it on client-side ? If it need's a knowing `javascript` would you produce some code sample.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/singhakash07/a2seK/135/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be achieved using the tablesorter jquery plugin.

Below is the html code - note that i have omitted jsp specific stuff since this is not relevant to the answer.
Remember to download this plugin and place it in an accessible location

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/blue/style.css" type="text/css" id="" media="print, projection, screen" />
</head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" id="js">

$(document).ready(function()
 {
  $("#myTable").tablesorter();
 }
);

</script>
<body>
<select id="MySorter">
  <option value="name">Faculty name</option>
  <option value="budgetSeats">Budget seats</option>
  <option value="totalSeats">Total Seats</option>
</select>

<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
<tr>
 <th>Faculty name</th>
 <th>Faculty budget seats</th>
 <th>Faculty total seats</th>
 
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td>Smith</td>
 <td>20</td>
 <td>15</td>
 
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Doe</td>
 <td>30</td>
 <td>10</td>
 
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Bach</td>
 <td>10</td>
 <td>10</td>
 
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Conway</td>
 <td>40</td>
 <td>50</td>
 
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>



<script>

$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $( "#MySorter" ).change(function() {
    //alert('value-'+$( "#MySorter" ).val());
    var sortColumn = $( "#MySorter" ).val();
    if(sortColumn == 'name'){
   $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0]]} );
    }else if(sortColumn == 'budgetSeats') {
   $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[1,0]]} );
    }else if(sortColumn == 'totalSeats'){
   $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[2,0]]} );
    }
    
  });
    } 
); 
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the table using e.g JQuery table sorter. Just add all the values to the table and sort it on client.

See [the example](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

UPDATE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
```

and sort

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); 
    } 
);
```

Comment: do I need a table sorter jquery plugin ? I include jquery library and link the script's to it and created tablesorter.js , but it doesn't seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look of the following links to order an array using JS:

- [Using JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript)
- [Using JS or JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503900/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-with-jquery-or-javascript)