# Sort JSON response alphabetically using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

The server returns the following response from a query:

```
       { ROM: "Romania", 
         YUG: "Yugoslavia",
         PRT: "Portugal", 
         MKD: "Macedonia", 
         GRC: "Greece",
         FRA: "France", 
         ISL: "Iceland", 
         LUX: "Luxembourg", 
         HUN: "Hungary", 
         GBR: "United Kingdom", 36 more… }
```

I need to put these into an already existing select like so:

```
 $.each(result, function(key, value) { 

        $('#country')
        .append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value",key)
        .text(value)); 

        });
```

Can someone tell me how to sort the countries alphabetically by value before inserting them into the html element?

Comment: You can do a sort on result.

Comment: First push your key-value pairs into an array, define a sort function, then run `array.sort(sortFunc)`. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503900/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-with-jquery-or-javascript.

Comment: This answer got me in the right track. I am able to sort the values and add them to the option element. Ultimately, I want to end up with the country code as the value attribute. Like so: <option value="FRA">France</option>. WIll play with it some more. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't sort objects but you can sort arrays, so you can create an array of `HTMLOptionElement`objects and sort it and then append it to the select element.

```
$('#country').append(function() {
    return $.map(result, function (key, value) {
        return new Option(key, value);
    }).sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.text.localeCompare(b.text);
    });
});
```

[Here is a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/xtuwf9v6/)

Comment: You sir, are a live saver!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the returned JSON, I'm assuming **result is your returned JSON**. *Kind of*

```
Object.keys(result).sort().reduce(function (a, b) { a[b] = result[b]; return a; }, {});
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtuwf9v6/2/)

---

That will sort the object. To sort the input:

```
$("#country").html(function () {  return $(this).find('option').sort(function(a,b){  return a.value-b.value  });  });
```

Replace `$("#country")` with the name of your select.

---

### Quick Plugin

This will add a `sortArray` function

```
$.fn.sortSelect=function(){this.html(function(){  return $(this).find('option').sort(function(a,b){return a.value-b.value});});}
```

Then you can do

```
$('#country').sortSelect()
```

Comment: In your first fragment, what is `key`? I guess it should be `b`. Anyway, this fragment is essentially making a copy of `result`. In real life it probably will work, but it depends on undocumented browser internals for handling the internals of key ordering. The engine is not obligated to deliver up the keys in the order in which they were added.

Answer (score 1):

```
function OrderListBy(prop) {
    return function (a, b) {
        if (a[prop] > b[prop]) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (a[prop] < b[prop]) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Call this function:** Sort by name -

```
YourArray.sort( OrderListBy("name") );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [item1, item2];
array.sort();
```

Comment: More detail and explanation would help here.