# Sort json response of api alphabetically

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I am trying to receive get api response in an alphabetically sorted order. I have tried the second answer from this question - [Sort JSON response alphabetically using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908744/sort-json-response-alphabetically-using-javascript)

My javascript code

```
function OrderListBy(prop) {
  return function (a, b) {
    if (a[prop] > b[prop]) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a[prop] < b[prop]) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  };
}

router.get('/countries', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const countries = await Country.find({}, 'name');
    const sortedCountries = countries.sort(OrderListBy('name'));
    res.send(sortedCountries);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send();
  }
});
```

OUTPUT

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5f0ccf5f45a1a51ca99382a3",
        "name": "Australia"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5eb6c2e94298400b6eb6ca3c",
        "name": "India"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ec68ca5325d997b752056cd",
        "name": "china"
    }
]
```

it should return China before India alphabetically. Its returning the countries in order they created.
This isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say it isn't working, do you mean it's giving you an error? Or is it not returning what you wanted? Can you share the output?

Comment: Why don't you sort them here: `await Country.find({}, 'name');` ?

Comment: Seems like sorting works correctly what is the output of `countries`?

Comment: Output updated please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort it in the query itself. Try this

```
await Country.find({}, {'name': 1}).sort({name: 1})
```

Note: Inside sort, follow below values depending on result is required in which order.

```
1 Ascending
-1 Descending
```