# Sort a list alphabetically with characters at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to sort a list in angular, alphabetically(ascending) but want the special characters if any prefixed to an item to be pushed at the end of the list.
For e.g: the list should like:

```
Apple
Banana
*Apple
```

any suggestions would be recommended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503900/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-with-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: Not a duplicate, but not that far off...

Comment: Just use `sort()` callback function and add `z` on strings starting with special chars, check my answer.

Comment: @AndyRay thnxx for the awsome solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple solution. When manually comparing strings it's good practice to use [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) which will correctly sort even when the user's language specific locale dictates a different sort order. But that function alone won't solve our problem. Building on top of @wZVanG's clever answer, we'll replace any non-word characters, using the `\W` regex character group, at the beginning of the string with the letter `z` which will automatically sort them to the end of the list.

Note one flaw in this is that if any of your words start with more than one `z` they will get sorted after the special characters. A simple workaround is to add more `z`s to the string, as in `return a.replace(/^\W+/, 'zzz').localeCompare(b.replace(/^\W+/, 'zzz')`.

```
var array = ["Banana", "Apple", "*Canana", "Blackberry", "Banana", "*Banana", "*Apple"];

array.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.replace(/^\W+/, 'z').localeCompare(b.replace(/^\W+/, 'z'));
});
```

Comment: Note `\W` will also take underscore `_` and will be ordered as `_Apple, Banana, *Apple`. You may want to `/^[^a-z]+/i`

Comment: I had a similar problem with sorting a list in python instead of java. Adapting the solution provided by @AndyRay to python syntax solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not correct but its the best I can think of at this hour.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mmycny4z/)

```
var array = ["Apple", "Banana", "*Apple"];

// Split the arrays with and without special chars
var alphaNumeric = array.filter(function (val) {
    return !(/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(val));
});
var specialChars = array.filter(function (val) {
    return /[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(val);
});

console.log(alphaNumeric, specialChars);

// Sort them individually
alphaNumeric.sort();
specialChars.sort();

// Bring them back together but put the special characters one afterwards
var both = alphaNumeric.concat(specialChars);

console.log(both);
```

Comment: works.. not the ideal one though but does that for  me, thx:)

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = ["Apple","Orange", "Banana", "*Banana","*Apple"];
regex= /^[A-z]+$/;
dummyArray1=[];
dummyArray2=[];
for(var i =0;i< list.length; i++){

    if(regex.test(list[i][0])){
    dummyArray1.push(list[i]);
    }
    else{
    dummyArray2.push(list[i]);
    }
}

console.log(dummyArray1.sort());
console.log(dummyArray2.sort());
console.log(dummyArray1.concat(dummyArray2));
```

Answer (score 1):

One line:

```js
var sorted = ["Banana", "Apple", "*Canana", "Blackberry", "/Banana", "*Banana", "*Apple"]
.sort(function(a, b, r){
   return r = /^[a-z]/i, (r.test(a) ? a : "z" + a) > (r.test(b) ? b : "z" + b)
});


//Test
document.write(sorted.join("<br />"));
```

Add `Z` if the item does not begin with a letter of the alphabet.