# Order by date multidimensional object

Tags: jquery, json, sorting, object

I have a Json Object like this:

```
"value": {
    "date": {
        "2017-03-10": {
            "0": {
                "buy": 0,
                "sell": 0
            },
            "1": {
                "buy": 0,
                "sell": 0
            },
            "2": {
                "buy": 0,
                "sell": 0
            },
        },
    },}
```

I have all dates in: Multi_Obj["value"]["date"];

and if i use the command sort:

```
Multi_Obj["value"]["date"].sort(function(a, b) {
a = new Date(a.dateModified);
b = new Date(b.dateModified);
return a>b ? -1 : a<b ? 1 : 0;});
```

I have this result:

Uncaught TypeError: Multi_Obj.show_data.sort is not a function.

Please Help Me! :)

Comment: sort can be use with array not with object

Comment: `Multi_Obj.value.date.sort(function(a, b) {`

Comment: The keys of objects cannot be ordered. What you're trying to do here is not possible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5503957/4248328

Comment: NB: This has nothing to do with JSON. Please read the usage info on the `json` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort associated arrays because of how they are built in JavaScript, but you can sort it, if you convert it to a tuple.  So, if you used to have:

```
colorPreference = {"favorate":"blue","hate","red"}
```

The tuple version would be:

```
colorPreference = [["favorate","blue"],["hate","red"]]
```

You still have both the key and the value, but now it's in an array-based format which **does** enforce order.  Associated arrays **do not** enforce order of it's elements.

So, what does our JavaScript look like then:

```
function toTuples(assocArray) {
    var tuples = [];
    for (var key in assocArray) tuples.push([key, assocArray[key]]);
    return tuples;
}

console.log(toTuples(Multi_Obj["value"]["date"]).sort(function(a, b) {
    a = new Date(a[0]);
    b = new Date(b[0]);
    return a>b ? -1 : a<b ? 1 : 0;
}));
```

If you're wondering, you can't really convert it back, because then the order would not be preserved.  But you can still loop through it:

```
for (var i = 0, len = output.length; i < len; i++) {
    key = output[i][0];
    value = output[i][1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You [should not rely on a certain order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38218582/5459839) of object properties, even though some newer ES6 methods will guarantee a certain order, but not one you can set arbitrary with a call to `sort`.

You could instead create an ES6 [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which acts much like a plain object, but which retains *insertion* order. This you can use as follows:

```js
const obj = {
    "value": {
        "date": {
            "2017-12-01": "a",
            "2017-03-10": "b",
            "2017-05-20": "c",
            "2016-01-01": "d"
        }
    }
};

// Convert date property to a sorted Map:
obj.value.date = Object.keys(obj.value.date)
    .sort( (a, b) => Date.parse(a) - Date.parse(b) )
    .reduce( (mp, a) => mp.set(a, obj.value.date[a]), new Map );

// Display results (sorted):
obj.value.date.forEach( (value, date) => console.log(date, value) );
```

Note that the syntax to use with a Map is a bit different. To get one particular entry, you would use the `get` method:

```
obj.value.date.get('2017-03-10')
```